# Vectors in c++ is giving error segmentation fault while performing push_back? code is attached.!

Tags: vector, segmentation-fault, push-back

segmentation fault is occurring just after the `push_back` in the first loop.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
vector<int> a;

int main() {
  int i,n,k,q,temp;

  cin>>n>>k>>q;
  for ( i =0;i<n;i++)
  {
    cin>>temp;
    a.push_back(temp);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Vectors in c++ is giving error segmentation fault while performing `push_back` !

Comment: Did you enter a number, or something else?

Comment: You should give us the input you use.